# Launching Tensorboard - NameError: name 'tensorboard' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm attempting to launch tensorboard and view a graph I created.

```
import tensorflow as tf

logPath = "C:\\path\\to\\log" -- can also be /path/to/log

sess = tf.Session()
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logPath, sess.graph)
```

This code runs fine and creates a event file in the proper folder, but when I run this command in the shell:

```
tensorboard --logdir /path/to/log
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
tensorboard --logdir /path/to/log
NameError: name 'tensorboard' is not defined
```

Am I missing a setting? I've seen the ONE other question with this error but that solution didn't solve this issue.

I have been able to assign nodes and work purely in the command line okay, I just want to start testing the visualzation.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you are entering the command `tensorboard` at the Python shell. However, `tensorboard` is actually the name of a Windows executable program, and not a Python command.
Therefore, you instead run TensorBoard by entering the same command at the "`C:\>`" Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding to the top of your script:

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

Comment: This helps when you are using keras.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It could be: you are writing "tensorboard" instead of "TensorBoard"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).